# Is every measure in $\mathbb R^n$ a "combination" of Lebesgue measure and the Counting measure

Tags: measure-theory

The Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem states that every $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ can be decomposed in $\mu = \nu_0 + \nu_1$ where $\nu_0 \ll \mu$ and $\nu_1 \perp \mu$.
Now, I know that the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and the counting measure $\delta$ are orthogonal. Thus, I wonder if the decomposition theorem is also telling me that
$\mu = \nu_0' + \nu_1$, such that $\nu'_0 \ll \lambda$ and $\nu_1 \ll \delta$. For simplicity, let's assume that we are in $\mathbb R^n$, so the Lebesgue measure and the counting measure do exist.

Comment: No. Consider the cantor 1/3 distribution. This is a measure that is singular with respect the lebesgue measure and is continuous.

Comment: Is it also singular to the counting measure?

Comment: The counting measure on $[0,1]$ is not sigma finite. In any event, the cantor measure has no atomic simpletons.

Comment: You might be interested in the Section 'Refinement' in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem

Comment: @DaviBarreira: the most general decomposition for $\sigma$-finite measures on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is $\mu=\nu_a+\nu_c+\nu_d$ where $\nu\ll\lambda$, $\lambda\perp(\nu_c+\nu_d)$, $\nu_c\perp\nu_d$, $\nu_c(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and if $\nu_d\neq0$,  $\nu_d$ is a purely atomic measure supported in a countable discrete set. This can be dome by decompossing the distribution $F^*=F\mu-F_{\mu_a}$ in its purely jump part and its continuous part.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @OliverDiaz! I had read the wikipedia page, but it was not totally clear. BTW, the singular continuous measure, is there a "base" measure for it? I mean, is every singular continuous measure absolutely continuous to each other?